# ProGuard config

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation, ksoap2

I use ksoap2 library in my android project. When I use ProGuard to build my app, some of ksoap2 features not work any more.

As you know progaurding app when it contains ksoap2 library makes some conflicts. For resolving this issue I used 3 different proguard-configs and then delete xmlpull in library but still soap objects in ksoap2 not working after proguarding.

So My problem is this: "ksoap2 not work correctly after proguard" and
I want :"a proguard-config or some suggestion for this issue"

Here are part of codes that I used for proguard-comfig:

```
-libraryjars libs\ksoap2-android-assembly.jar
-dontwarn org.kobjects.**
-dontwarn org.ksoap2.**
-dontwarn org.kxml2.**
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
```

then I add this too:

```
-keep class org.kobjects.** { *; }
-keep class org.ksoap2.** { *; }
-keep class org.kxml2.** { *; }
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
```

then I add this too:

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses    
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
```

and I try deleting xmlpull too, but still ksoap2 doesn't work correctly after proguarding app.

**Edit**:

1- I have no error and building signed apk with using ProGuard done.
2- Every thing works correct when I run app or sign apk without proguard.

Comment: Please post your full logcat error.

Comment: There is no error! Just after proguarding object requests not send anymore.

Comment: Just post that full error here.

Comment: Just try to remove the `-libraryjars libs\ksoap2-android-assembly.jar` line from your proguard file and then check

Comment: There is no error! The problem just appears when I build a signed apk with proguard, in this situation I can't access logcat, I justed put it in try catch and toast the message: "Unknown"

Comment: I removed that too, not work!

Comment: Does it shows anything in the console ?

Comment: No, it shows nothing!

Comment: Have you tried `-dontshrink`?

Comment: it was for a long time ago!  I wrote a library by myself and delete ksoap library,  mine is works perfect in last 3 years!